# I pass all test spf,dmarc,dkim but still email going into spam

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04, postfix-mta

I am using amazon ec2 ubuntu 14.04 instance and  i did configure postfix,dkim and spf but still email are coming into inbox.Below you can see the orignal msg.
[image]

```
Delivered-To: malikkamranabid@gmail.com
Received: by 10.46.36.3 with SMTP id k3csp2397059ljk;
        Sun, 25 Feb 2018 02:44:16 -0800 (PST)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: AG47ELso8sEH+HXagEwS+Cp3omW50lz8Zg7pnhNvaYcsvQjzjA3ezzCRkOZII/vpg/Dws4WboCl+ 
X-Received: by 10.55.168.4 with SMTP id r4mr11222502qke.311.1519555456508;
        Sun, 25 Feb 2018 02:44:16 -0800 (PST)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1519555456; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=bs3mUdAYvaINS8ojtjqe6SkOBmcUEIiWFDx2pxqxVqVoQjv48OJbFqfcOo9xsjuBNV
         7GOEf+9Y33e+sxQEgUdnKnhsR7BDf1zCRb56mdDZLUrUUrMbJmkcADAGkzbAshdAnNH2
         PHmrozAYOGzHUxhGqx8GxdGFp4dfvcFyQ4vv7XUo42jTcvEE72d6IU62s883sFMMhEei
         KecC7gpsSESHi+GR/SO2J5cwgw8/7bVstZB4EMbUc4FRkCDAoW14WUdjpYifVIDGJ6eo
         F+Yy/YOnkdSHqArkh1ECbAdVxducy5Ech7n293IgwWkVbAVPB7gs0rdpbWh9R6mYAAQH
         nuYA== ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=date:message-id:cc:reply-to:from:mime-version:subject:to
         :dkim-signature:arc-authentication-results;
        bh=z6TUz85EdYrACGMHYgZhJGvVy5oQI0dooVMKa2ZT7c4=;
        b=SiayPbnRmwqPYvN/3fDjKeb9AlUFUybSFOjuk6wbwNKOkm67rTByIHSCqyDsyNpALJ
         aNsFUe6TJY+4ADJwfTfekBTAbs6DJthyLR47ELn6G2R7FTDebmg6eu6sZsCrX9mrrGGT
         rCKIvfnPq+56TvU7UYzZvicnw/nnUaA1GmJKQAAn0/94ZlPgf4Q/Qf4QKGUpag/65DTI
         UTzttdeioLEAwaRcbSzOEd77I2e5sv+1VIsn8dPM+zYwbaK5Lic/Zz4y/o3Z2cm6IwcF
         UZmUAB+0Nm01O2U1qXUyVnN4wTrjAp5ruYVNwwCTp7la3RolM9r4gtTaj2T+JYaJKDx+
         Viug== ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@lnl.com.hk header.s=dkim header.b=oyNNr3rQ;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of noreply@lnl.com.hk designates 54.210.33.152 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=noreply@lnl.com.hk;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=lnl.com.hk Return-Path: <noreply@lnl.com.hk>
Received: from mail.lnl.com.hk (ec2-54-210-33-152.compute-1.amazonaws.com. [54.210.33.152])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id m5si5766866qkd.12.2018.02.25.02.44.16
        for <malikkamranabid@gmail.com>;
        Sun, 25 Feb 2018 02:44:16 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of noreply@lnl.com.hk designates 54.210.33.152 as permitted sender) client-ip=54.210.33.152;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@lnl.com.hk header.s=dkim header.b=oyNNr3rQ;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of noreply@lnl.com.hk designates 54.210.33.152 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=noreply@lnl.com.hk;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=lnl.com.hk
Received: by mail.lnl.com.hk (Postfix, from userid 33) id 34432426FE; Sun, 25 Feb 2018 10:44:17 +0000 (UTC)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=simple/simple; d=lnl.com.hk; s=dkim; t=1519555457; bh=z6TUz85EdYrACGMHYgZhJGvVy5oQI0dooVMKa2ZT7c4=; h=To:Subject:From:Reply-To:CC:Date:From; b=oyNNr3rQhOdPqaNvZfQv2Fx6C/Ypx6T4SLKyhihBIP3I5A/8Q3NeY/VbFOEdshIvL    pKl1cRm+RzbdNKJULdUCklWJBIoi1EIiAlvUh0cWYTR1YQZo1/b+c2FKoNfK6N5E01      cFp+U1mmuuTXx19T8uQQBRlvZBLUTMuNIq0OvFA8=
To: malikkamranabid@gmail.com
Subject: My subject
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 1000:emailphp.php
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
From: noreply@lnl.com.hk
Reply-To: malikkamranabid@gmail.com
CC: malikkamranabid94@yahoo.com X-Mailer: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.22
Message-Id: <20180225104417.34432426FE@mail.lnl.com.hk> Date: Sun, 25 Feb 2018 10:44:17 +0000 (UTC)

Hello world!
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using an elastic IP address for your mail server, you need to do that.

If you are...

```
Received: from mail.lnl.com.hk (ec2-54-210-33-152.compute-1.amazonaws.com. [54.210.33.152])
```

...then you haven't asked AWS Support to configure reverse DNS on your EIP, which you will definitely want to do.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/reverse-dns-for-ec2s-elastic-ip-addresses/

There is nothing obvious contributing to this message going into spam, but it would not be surprising if gmail gives some weight to the default `*.compute-1.amazonaws.com` reverse DNS record, which clearly identifes the source as a dynamic or pool address, which is a potential red flag indicating a transient sender (spammer).

*Afterthought: The `From` address as interpreted by gmail is distinctly wrong.  Verify that your messages aren't actually malformed.  You need this to look correct.  The CC line looks invalid in the message body, as well.*

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a reverse DNS lookup issue. Without a valid reverse DNS record, many ISPs will block your email or mark it as spam.

See this line?

'Received: from mail.lnl.com.hk (ec2-54-210-33-152.compute-1.amazonaws.com. [54.210.33.152]'

The IP address 54.210.33.152 reverse lookup PTR record returns ec2-54-210-33-152.compute-1.amazonaws.com, not mail.lnl.com.hk. This is a big red flag in most spam scoring systems. It's probably affecting you here.

For more info on reverse DNS, see https://www.rackaid.com/blog/email-dns-records/